# User normal username and not emails in asp.net identity 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In a new MVC5 application with latest identity, how i can use normal username instead of the default email.

Now identity is duplicating the email in both email and username field.

I want to be able to accept normal usernames and being able to put them in the register controller action.

Answer (score 0):

In the Model folders of your project, there is a UserManager.

Just make some changes to the UserValidator:

```
manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                // Initial config
                //AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                //RequireUniqueEmail = true
                // Current config
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
                RequireUniqueEmail = false
            };
```

You can also changes password preferences in this class, under the PasswordValidator property.